# Error "Software caused connection abort" that doesn't appear when using hotspot?

Tags: networking, ftp, connection, sftp, filezilla

I'm trying to connect to a server through [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/) via SFTP, but I encounter a problem. Logs:

```
14:07:10    Status: Connecting to 178.62.11.187...
14:07:11    Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
14:07:11    Trace:  CSftpConnectOpData::Send() in state 0
14:07:11    Trace:  Going to execute C:\Program Files\FileZilla FTP Client\fzsftp.exe
14:07:11    Response:   fzSftp started, protocol_version=8
14:07:11    Trace:  CSftpConnectOpData::ParseResponse() in state 0
14:07:11    Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
14:07:11    Trace:  CSftpConnectOpData::Send() in state 3
14:07:11    Command:    open "hdodov@178.62.11.187" 22
14:07:11    Trace:  Connecting to 178.62.11.187 port 22
14:07:11    Trace:  We claim version: SSH-2.0-PuTTY_Local:_Jul_12_2017_08:57:39
14:07:16    Trace:  Network error: Software caused connection abort
14:07:16    Error:  Network error: Software caused connection abort
14:07:16    Trace:  CSftpControlSocket::OnTerminate without error
14:07:16    Trace:  CControlSocket::DoClose(66)
14:07:16    Trace:  CSftpControlSocket::ResetOperation(66)
14:07:16    Trace:  CControlSocket::ResetOperation(66)
14:07:16    Error:  Could not connect to server
14:07:16    Trace:  CFileZillaEnginePrivate::ResetOperation(66)
```

Here are some facts:

- The error occurs **before** a connection is established.
- I get the same result when connecting as `anonymous`.
- A friend **can** make a connection with the exact same host, username and password from another network.
- I **can** connect to *other* servers via SFTP.
- **I *can* connect with the exact same configuration, but only while tethered to my [Samsung Galaxy Young S6310](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_young_s6310-5280.php) and using its Mobile Data.**
- Setting up port forwarding with the following settings didn't fix it:

  ```
  | Service Port | IP Address    | Internal Port | Protocol   | Status  |  
  | ------------ | ------------- | ------------- | ---------- | ------- |  
  | 22           | 192.168.0.101 | 22            | TCP or UDP | Enabled |
  ```
- Reinstalling FileZilla didn't work.
- Restarting my router didn't work.
- Restarting my computer didn't work.
- Disabling Firewall didn't work.
- Using another FTP Client ([SmartFTP](https://www.smartftp.com/)) didn't work. It throws [the same error](https://www.smartftp.com/support/kb/74).
- Requests towards the server time out:

  ```
  Pinging findgreatquotes.com [178.62.11.187] with 32 bytes of data:
  Request timed out.
  Request timed out.
  Request timed out.
  Request timed out.

  Ping statistics for 178.62.11.187:
      Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss)
  ```

  **Yet I *can* still open http://findgreatquotes.com/?!**

Here are the results from `tracert`:

```
Tracing route to findgreatquotes.com [178.62.11.187]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.0.1
  2     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  212-5-152-1.ip.btc-net.bg [212.5.152.1]
  3     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  37.192.236.94-optic-com.eu [94.236.192.37]
  4     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  212-39-69-153.ip.btc-net.bg [212.39.69.153]
  5    36 ms    36 ms    36 ms  ae-14.r24.frnkge08.de.bb.gin.ntt.net [129.250.6.242]
  6    58 ms    58 ms    58 ms  ae-5.r24.londen12.uk.bb.gin.ntt.net [129.250.3.12]
  7    28 ms    28 ms    28 ms  prag-bb1-link.telia.net [80.91.247.82]
  8   114 ms    41 ms    79 ms  hbg-bb1-link.telia.net [213.155.136.132]
  9    53 ms    55 ms    69 ms  ldn-bb3-link.telia.net [62.115.122.165]
 10    54 ms    53 ms    52 ms  ldn-b4-link.telia.net [62.115.136.43]
 11    57 ms    57 ms    47 ms  digitalocean-ic-306494-ldn-b3.c.telia.net [62.115.44.250]
 12     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 13     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 ..
 ..
```

Apparently, the problem lies somewhere in my router or my network settings. **What could be the reason for such an error under the given circumstances?**

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the server hosting platform has banned your IP.

Comment: Oh.............